# How to store string to txt file

Tags: c, string, scanf

```
void inserting()
{
    char file_name[50]; 
    char sentence[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    printf("File name (With extn):");
    scanf("%s", file_name);
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "a");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    scanf("%s", sentence);

    fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);    
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
    fclose(fptr);
}
```

I want to store content from string to file... but it is displaying everything except the first word..

```
INPUT : Hello this is C program //which I have entered
OUTPUT: this is C program //this is what stored in file
```

Comment: Print the strings to screen before storing them to see what they contain.

Comment: @klutt yeah i tried, surprisingly it is only displaying first word not rest of it

Comment: Exactly. My point here is that the problem has absolutely nothing to do with file handling. Learn to create a [mre]

Comment: @klutt apologies I'm new here... still i don't know how to fix this problem

Comment: No worries. Learning how to ask is a skill as much as learning how to program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void inserting()
{
    char file_name[50]="C:\\Users\\Dev Parzival\\Desktop\\foo.txt";
    char sentence[1000];
    FILE *fptr;
    //printf("File name (With extn):");
    //scanf("%s", file_name);
    fptr = fopen(file_name, "w");
    if (fptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error!");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", sentence);
    printf(sentence);

    //fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);
    fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
    fclose(fptr);
}

int main(){
    inserting();
}
```

scan will not read spaces with`%s` u have to include spaces also I assume thats why use `%[^\n]`format specifier.

Comment: It executes fine on my system modify as u wish. Hope it helps : )

Answer (score 0):

If you want to preserve your code make the adjustment

```
void inserting(){
        char file_name[50]; 
        char sentence[1000];
        FILE *fptr;
        printf("File name (With extn):");
        scanf("%s", file_name);
        fptr = fopen(file_name, "a");
        if (fptr == NULL)
        {
            printf("Error!");
            exit(1);
        }
        printf("Enter a sentence:\n");
        scanf("%s", sentence);
        fprintf(fptr,"%s",sentence); //<-- HERE
        fgets(sentence,sizeof(sentence),stdin);    
        fprintf(fptr, "%s", sentence);
        fclose(fptr);
    }
```

Or you can use something like `getline` just to be cleaner.